# updating DNS of Existing VNET using template

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

Thanks in advance, I'm new to ARM templates and still learning how it works.
I've a VNET with resources in it, VNET address space is 10.0.0.0/16 and it contains one single subnet with address space 10.0.0.0/16
I'm trying to update the DNS using ARM template and it throws me an error

```
"New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 11.50.14 PM - Error: Code=InvalidTemplate; Message=Deployment template validation failed: 'The provided value for the template parameter 'virtualNetworkSubnetaddress' at line 
'26' and column '40' is not valid.'."
```

This is my deployment file

```
{

  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",

  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",

  "parameters": {

    "location": {

      "type": "string",

      "metadata": {

        "Description": "The region to deploy the resources into"

      }

    },

    "virtualNetworkName": {

      "type": "string",

      "metadata": {

        "Description": "The name of the Virtual Network"

      }

    },

    "virtualNetworkAddressRange": {

      "type": "string",

      "metadata": {

        "Description": "The address range of the virtual network in CIDR format"

      },

      "defaultValue": "10.0.0.0/16"

    },


    "virtualNetworkSubnetaddress": {

      "type": "array",

      "metadata": {

        "Description": "The subnet definition for the virtual network"

      }

    },

    "dnsAddress": {

      "type": "array",

      "metadata": {

        "Description": "The DNS address(es) of the DNS Server(s) used by the virtual network"

      }

    },
  },

  "resources": [

    {

      "name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",

      "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",

      "location": "[parameters('location')]",

      "apiVersion": "2018-02-01",

      "properties": {

        "addressSpace": {

          "addressPrefixes": [

            "[parameters('virtualNetworkAddressRange')]"

          ]

        },

        "dhcpOptions": {

          "dnsServers": "[parameters('dnsAddress')]"

        },

        "subnets": "[parameters('virtualNetworkSubnetaddress')]"

      }

    }

  ],

  "outputs": {}

}
```

Below is my parameter file

```
{

  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",

  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",

  "parameters": {
    "dnsaddress": {

      "value": ["10.0.0.4"]

    },
    "location": {

      "value": "East US"

    },
    "virtualNetworkAddressRange": {

      "value": "10.0.0.0/16"

    },
    "virtualNetworkName": {

      "value": "vnettest"

    },
    "virtualNetworkSubnetaddress": {

      "value": ["10.0.0.0/16"]

    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I tried using [] bracket and Getting error

**"{"code":"DeploymentFailed","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-debug for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":"{\r\n \"error\": {\r\n \"code\": \"InvalidRequestFormat\",\r\n \"message\": \"Cannot parse the request.\",\r\n \"details\": [\r\n {\r\n \"code\": \"InvalidJson\",\r\n \"message\": \"Error converting value \\"10.0.0.0/16\\" to type 'Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Networking.Nrp.Frontend.Contract.Csm.Public.Subnet'. Path 'properties.subnets[0]', line 1, position 153.\"\r\n }\r\n ]\r\n }\r\n}"}]}"**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your template expects array as the value for `virtualNetworkSubnetaddress` and you are passing in a string. value should be this:

```
"value": [
    "10.0.0.0/16"
]
```

Json syntax reading: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/an-introduction-to-json

Comment: thanks for looking into it, I've tried it and it was giving a different error before. I didn't specified it while raising the request because I thought I'm doing something wrong. I've updated my question with exact error.
I'm thinking there is something wrong with the data types and I'm passing string here

Comment: thats a completely different question. I suggest you accept this answer and start a new question

Comment: thanks for the help, I'll post a new question with the same error which I've highlighted.